# Any Other Reasons for Maven "Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor" Besides Proxy

Tags: proxy, maven-3

This error in other posts I'm told is a result of the proxy not being set up properly

however I do have our proxy set up correctly in settings.xml (we don't have user/password)

Is there any other cause for this maven error ?

```
i.e.: 


  .m2>

<settings>
  <proxies>
   <proxy>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>proxy.ours.net</host>
      <port>8080</port>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
</settings>


 C:>mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany
.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -Dinte
ractiveMode=false
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://uk.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plu
gin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:mave
n-clean-plugin:2.5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or on
e of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5
Downloading: http://uk.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-p
lugin/2.4/maven-install-plugin-2.4.pom

etc

       [WARNING] Failure to transfer org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from http://u
k.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be re
attempted until the update interval of UK has elapsed or updates are forced. Ori
ginal error: Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml fr
om/to UK (http://uk.maven.org/maven2): Not authorized by proxy , ReasonPhrase:Pr
oxy Authentication Required.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

Comment: Based on the error message it seemed to be that you need an authorization for your proxy `Not authorized by proxy , ReasonPhrase:Proxy Authentication Required.`

Comment: Yes I had seen that message as well. But our browser references to the proxy don't need any user/passwords. Perhaps there is such a thing as a "smart" proxy that here is not allowing maven. (This is a large org and hard to track this down but I'll look further.) It does allow individual http maven jar download. Maybe the command line execution causes maven to use ftp or another protocol ?

Comment: The command line does not change the protocoll. Apart from that maven uses never ftp only in old versions if you explicit configure that. Which is a little bit odd why do you use the uk mirror directly instead of using the default url `http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/` Ah...btw which Maven version do you use?

Comment: I found out they have smart proxy and my network user/pass enables it to work ok. (I had tried the mirror in case it was a restict url issue. I had had the same results with central). So problem solved. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While proxy normally didn't need user/password for maven build downloads  user/password was needed.

Comment: Where did you find it?

Comment: It was more a case of trial and error. Seems we have a smart proxy but I don't know the details.

Comment: So it was our proxy that was not allowing to download maven jars.